# how to merge almost identical values into a dictionary?

Tags: python

Hi I have a set of dictionaries that are almost identical:

```
{
    "item": "(L) Shirt",
},
{
    "item": "(M) Shirt",
},
{
    "item": "(S) Shirt",
}
{
    "item": "Shirt",
}
```

My expected output was to merge them into one and another key, pair value in a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "item":  "Shirt",
    "sizes": ["L", "M", "S"]
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed with this so I asked for help. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: post your current code. What if some "brand" differs from others?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you! your question is truly correct because the brand doesn't matter at all. I have edited it.

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do here. I think the data structure here is not correct. `Sizes` have been lumped into `Item`. It just needs a split that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only a *"size unit"* prefix in `"item"` key's value makes a difference:

```
d1 = {"item": "(L) Shirt", "brand": "Hanes"}
d2 = {"item": "(M) Shirt", "brand": "Hanes"}
d3 = {"item": "(S) Shirt", "brand": "Hanes"}

clothes_groups = {"sizes": set()}
for d in [d1, d2, d3]:
    clothes_groups["brand"] = d["brand"]
    size, product = d["item"].split() if d["item"].startswith('(') else (None, d["item"])
    clothes_groups["item"] = product
    if size: clothes_groups["sizes"].add(size[1:-1])

print(clothes_groups)
```

The output:

```
{'sizes': {'M', 'L', 'S'}, 'brand': 'Hanes', 'item': 'Shirt'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import re

data = [{'item': '(L) Shirt', 'brand': 'Hanes'}, {'item': '(M) Shirt', 'brand': 'Hanes'}, {'item': '(S) Shirt', 'brand': 'Hanes'}]

result = {}
for i in data:
    if i["brand"] not in result:
        result[i["brand"]] = {}
    size = re.match(r"\((.*?)\)", i["item"]).group(1)     #Get Size
    item = re.sub(r"\(.*?\)", "", i["item"]).strip()      #Get Item
    if item not in result[i["brand"]]:
        result[i["brand"]][item] = {"item": item, "brand": i["brand"], "sizes": []}
    result[i["brand"]][item]["sizes"].append(size)        #Create Required DS

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Hanes': {'Shirt': {'brand': 'Hanes',
                     'item': 'Shirt',
                     'sizes': ['L', 'M', 'S']}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You coul use `pandas`. You would first extract features for each of your items: `size`& `item` name. Then, for each product set the `size` column to the combination of all available sizes for that specific product:

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

list1 = [{"item": "(L) Shirt","brand": "Hanes"},{"item": "(M) Shirt","brand": "Hanes"},{"item": "(S) Shirt","brand": "Hanes"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df['size'] = df.item.apply(lambda x : re.findall('\(([^\)]+)\)', x)[0])
df['item'] =  df.item.apply(lambda x : x.split(') ')[1])
df['size'] = df.apply(lambda row : list(df[(df.brand == row['brand']) & (df.item == row['item'])]['size']), axis = 1)

print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'item']).to_dict('r'))
```

**Output**

> [{'brand': 'Hanes', 'item': 'Shirt', 'size': ['L', 'M', 'S']}]